# Should you use a hashbang on AJAX content sites, or just use normal URLs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, hashbang, graceful-degradation

So I am creating just a fairly normal content based website that is going to load new pages/content in via AJAX for a smoother user experience and some simple transitions. I see a ton of people using a hashbang for similar implementations.

My question is why not just use regular URLs and have server-side determine if the regular page should be served or JSON/XML/etc based on the XMLHttpRequest var? At my first glance here it seems to make more sense to have one URL and I am curious why I see no mentions of this idea/approach in my initial searchings. Perhaps I am just missing something...

**ANSWER**: I missed that updating a full URL without a page load was not possible before HTML5 history. That is where my confusion arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 1 url, users can't bookmark anything on your site.  So you need to do something.

So you can either use hashbangs (aka anchors), or, if you are targeting reasonably new browsers, [html5 history](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

You can't use regular urls because when you change a url, the entire page reloads.

Comment: I meant to come across as still updating the URL. I see now that the full page URL update is a recent feature with HTML5.

Comment: What I was saying is that I intended to update the URL and not just have one URL. I failed to see that prior to HTML5 history, you could not just update the full URL without a page load.